# How Quarkus RESTEasy reactive works before version 2.2?

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

We are currently using an older version of Quarkus, so I would want to understand the impact and consider if we should upgrade to the latest version.

I learnt that since version 2.2 Quarkus will run method on `I/O thread` or `Worker thread` depending on the method return type (https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/#new-world-new-rules), meaning blocking/sync method not returning `Uni`/`Multi`/`CompletionStage` will be automatically offloaded to a worker thread so that it will not block the I/O thread.

In our current implementation with the older version of Quarkus and RESTEasy Reactive (I think it is 1.12.2), for all the methods `not` returning `Uni`/`Multi`/`CompletionStage` I believe they will get called on the I/O thread because we are not using `@Blocking` on them. These methods include actions such as calling external APIs, accessing databases and accessing files, etc, so I assume it should be our responsibility to do these actions in a non-blocking/async manner by using reactive libraries, otherwise they will block the I/O thread (Given that not all these methods I mentioned are currently implemented using reactive libraries). But upgrading to the latest version will fix this issue as such methods will be offloaded to worker thread, am I correct?

P.S: By reading Quarkus doc I understand that a minimal amount of I/O threads can handle many concurrent requests. I am curious by default how many I/O threads are there and is this configurable? Thanks!

Comment: I think that regarding your code it will not have a great effect, I mean, If im not mistaken on quarkus 1.x all rest invocations where distached to a worker thread if you don't use the reactive extensions. If you block the IO/Thread quarkus will give you a warning when it detects the situation and its in your hands to add the @Blocking annotation or make the code reactive

Comment: hmm...by reading this https://quarkus.io/blog/resteasy-reactive-smart-dispatch/#new-world-new-rules I think prior to 2.2 with Quarkus Reactive the rest invocation is dispatched to I/O thread. I was thinking maybe we need to upgrade to the latest version in case any of our method is done in a blocking manner then it will block the I/O thread (given it is not returning Uni/CompletionStage ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that prior to Quarkus 2.2, the default for RESTEasy Reactive was to do handle the requests on the event-loop for all methods except when `@Blocking` was used.
It goes without saying that this means you need to not do any blocking IO (or have any long running operations for that matter) in these methods.

Quarkus uses 2*number_of_cpu_threads as the default number of event-loop threads it creates